# Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec, : line 52 did not have 6 elements

Tags: r

In the LEA package, I have used

```
pc = pca("scratch/gi10.str.txt.geno", scale = TRUE)
```

Now, I need to perfom Tracy-Widom tests on all eigenvalues.

```
# create file: tuto.tracyWidom - tracy-widom test information.
tw = tracy.widom(pc)
```

I get this error message:

```
Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  
:**line 52** did not have 6 elements
```

I have googled that error message and got no help.

I have opened the eigenvalues in a text editor. There is no header. The first five lines are:

```
53127.4
44107.2
14287.6
11011.3
9824.79
```

This is lines 50 - 53:

```
2444.28
2393.52
2229.11
6.61314E-011
```

Line 52 has got 6 elements as far as I can  make out.

Any ideas please?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`data.table`'s `fread()` reads this file just fine... give it a try

```
data.table::fread("2444.28
2393.52
2229.11
6.61314E-011")


#             V1
# 1: 2.44428e+03
# 2: 2.39352e+03
# 3: 2.22911e+03
# 4: 6.61314e-11
```

Comment: Thanks @Wimpel for your idea. I found out that the Tracy-Widom tests had already been done. It was just a matter of loading them.